# Can't get linux-image source

Tags: kernel

Probably I am missing something obvious. This gives:

apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r) 
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic'
E: Unable to find a source package for linux

And:

apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic'
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic

Comment: Do you have the source respositories enabled? It should work the way you suggest...

Comment: Yes, you're right. That was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: If you think that your question has been answered, you might want to accept it. Feel free to correct it as well if needed.

Comment: If @lemonslice answer solved your problem, should you accept it so other users can use it as reference?

Comment: Here I don't Found snd.aloop
, Anyone here who can help me ? anand@anand2:/lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/sound/drivers$ ls
pcsp

Answer (score 1):

To install kernel source you have to enable source repositories, that is have a `deb-src` line that corresponds to the main repository `deb` line in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. For instance,

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

After you can get the kernel source of the actual running kernel with

```
apt update
apt source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```